# create a dynamic sql from parameters passed in sybase

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase15

I have a parameter which can have n inputs which are , separated. 
example : asd,qwe,zxc
Now I need to create an sql from based on the parameter passed inside a stored procedure.
example : select asd ,qwe,zxc from table1 
Is this possible in sybase ase 15.7
Thanks
Rinu

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just concatenate the various elements into the desied SQL query and store it in a varchar variable. Then execute the query with 'exec(@yourvariable)'